# Regex for parsing uid from URL

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse UIDs from URLs. However regex is not something I am good at so seeking for some help.

Example Input:
`https://example.com/d/iazs9fEil/somethingelse?foo=bar`

Example Output:
`iazs9fEil`

What I've tried so far is

```
([/d/]+[\d\x])\w+
```

Which somehow works, but returns in with the `/d/` prefix, so the output is `/d/iazs9fEil`.

How to change the regex to not contain the /d/ prefix?

EDIT:

I've tried this regex `([^/d/]+[\d\x])\w+` which outputs the correct string which is `iazs9fEil`, but also returns the rest of the url, so here it is `somethingelse?foo=bar`

Comment: `re.search(r'/d/(\w+)', s).group(1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome, that works as expected, thank you! It is not working in regexr.com, but I guess that it is the python dependency. Works fine in python so its okay. Feel free to make this an answer and I'll accept it if you wish.

Comment: You need to use groups as mentioned by others. Just a tip though, if what you are looking for is consistently after the 4th forward slash, you can use string.split('/')[5] I often find this easier than regex for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Neil Spliting is my current approach, I just feel like regex is more robust, as this url is generater by third-party application (Grafana) and I am not in charge of the changes.

Comment: I wonder if you have got "incomplete escape \x" when trying your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the web regex tester (regexr.com) it was complaining about unescaped characters, so changing `/d/(\w+)` to `\/d\/(\w+)` fixed the warning, however, the output contains the `/d/` prefix (Only in regexr, python output is fine)

Comment: What is complaining? See `/d/(\w+)` test - https://regex101.com/r/VW4Sem/1. Do not escape what does not have to be escaped and you will avoid many troubles.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh you mean my initial regex, I just tested now, it works in regexr.com but python raises `sre_contants.error incomplete escape \x`.
What kind of regex wizard are you? :D

Comment: For testing this is quite good: https://regex101.com/  I usually use backslashes even in Python for special characters so that it is PCRE compliant and I can use the debugger function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you may use

```
match = re.search(r'/d/(\w+)', your_string)  # Look for a match
if match:                                    # Check if there is a match first
    print(match.group(1))                    # Now, get Group 1 value
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VW4Sem/1) and a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2Fd%2F(%5Cw%2B)):

[image]

**NOTE**

- `/` is not any special metacharacter, do not escape it in Python string patterns
- `([/d/]+[\d\x])\w+` matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more slashes or digits (see `[/d/]+`, a positive character class) and then a digit or (here, Python shows an error: `sre_contants.error incomplete escape \x`, probably it could parse it as `x`, but it is not the case), and then matches 1+ word chars. You put the `/d/` into a character class and it stopped matching a *char sequence*, `[/d/]+` matches slashes and digits in any order and amount, and certainly places this string into Group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try `(?<=/d/)[^/]+`

Explanation:

`(?<=/d/)` - positive lookbehind, assure that what's preceeding is `/d/`

`[^/]+` - match one or more characters other than `/`, so it matches everything until `/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVu7gu/3)

Comment: Please do not escape `/`, it is not any special metacharacter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group:

```
https?://.*?/d/([^/\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZEOVI/2)

Comment: I think you do not have to check for `http` at the start though. Do you think `http://d/1a2b3c4d5` is a possible input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ha, that is a fair point. Your answer is the right and most complete one. Upvoted yours.